# print list python <_csv.reader object at 0x104be66d8>

Tags: python, csv, reader

```
import csv
positive_vocab = [csv.reader(open('SentiWS_v1.8c/SentiWS_v1.8c_Positive.txt', 'r'), delimiter='|')]
negative_vocab = [csv.reader(open('SentiWS_v1.8c/SentiWS_v1.8c_Negative.txt', 'r'), delimiter='|')]

print(*positive_vocab)
```

How can I print this list without getting this error:

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x104be66d8>
```

Comment: All you've done so far is to put the csv reader itself into a list. `help(csv.reader)` has an example for using the reader.

Comment: That's not an error, it's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: so my fault, how can I print the content of the .txt file like this: 'word1' , 'word2', 'word3'...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `list comprehension` (if you need to do something with row)

```
result = [row for row in csv.reader(...)]
```

or `list()`

```
result = list(csv.reader(...))
```

--

ps. this gives list of lists `[ [row1-word1, row1-word2, ...], [row2-word1, ...], ...]`

Comment: perfect thx, but know some words look like this: NN\t0.0040\ or this   'ADJX\t0.0040\tbahnbrechenden when printing them out